# Difference between starting a background process in BASHRC vs Command Line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am trying to background a process automatically.

```
nohup program > /tmp/program.log 2>&1 < /dev/null &
disown
```

If I check if the process is running and start it on login via ".bashrc", the program starts but then DIES  when I exit.

BUT if I do exactly the same command on the command line, the program continues to run, in background, when I exit.

I can't find any difference in program environment between a bashrc start and a cli start. (The bashrc has almost nothing in it).  My understanding the program in both cases should be treated the same.

What is the difference, and how can I stop a bashrc started 'daemon' being killed when the shell exits.

PS: removing nohup makes no difference.  and I have watched the program running then dying from a separate login, when the starting login exits.

And before someone says anything... Adding "disown" after backgrounding the program in the bashrc did NOT fix it!

UPDATE:
  If the ssh login connection is killed (window closed or connection terminated suddenly) the program started in the bashrc continues to run, but that seems to be because the bash that started it is also still running (at least for the time being).
The background is only killed if you type "exit" for the bash, or the bash is killed (even with a untrappable signal 9!).

The PPID of the program (disowned by the shell) is 0  that is its parent is not the shell NOR the init process!  This the case regardless how it is started.

UPDATE 2...
background program started from bashrc...

```
# ps -jA w
   PID   PGID    SID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
   891    891    891 pts/2    Ss+    0:00 /bin/bash
   899    891    891 pts/2    Sl+    0:00 program
```

I killed that one then started it from command line...

```
   891    891    891 pts/2    Ss+    0:00 /bin/bash
   958    955    891 pts/2    Sl     0:00 program
```

Now when the shell exists the program does not exit.
So it looks like the only different is the PGID changed.

How can I start a process in a different PGID?

Comment: Could you tell us who owns who with `pstree -gTt` command?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this: on my machine, `program` keeps running after logout even if started from `.bashrc` as in your example

Comment: @Mathieu  The PPID of the disowned background process is 0.  that is neither init, nor bash.  It does not matter how bash is killed, when it dies the background process dies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Process groups are needed for job control, because a shell needs something to send job control signals to, e.g. when you type `fg`.  POSIX.1-2017 [states](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html)

> A command interpreter process supporting job control can allocate the terminal to different *jobs, or process groups*, by placing related processes in a single process group and associating this process group with the terminal

(italics are mine) This seems even to equate the concepts of "process group" and "job", although most people use the term "job" for process groups (and even children in the shell's own process group) that are registered in the shells *job table* (and may be removed from that table by the builtin `disown`)

So, if a shell doesn't want to start a child command (or even shell pipeline) under job control, it doesnt't create a new process group (by calling `setpgrp()`)

This happens e.g. when using process substitution

```
blah=$(sleep 1000 | sleep 1000)
```

(try it, and have a look at the output of `ps -jA w`!) and, apparently, when starting commands from `.bashrc`

`nohup <command>`, by itself, will not start a new process group, it only [ignores](https://gist.github.com/kohsuke/0eeb9bb43ca8d62643dd#file-nohup-c-L219#L219) `SIGHUP` and then executes `command`

Linux (and other OS'es when you install something like `util-linux`) has a command [setsid](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/setsid.1.html) that will [do what you expected](http://go2linux.garron.me/linux/2010/12/setsid-how-execute-commands-after-you-exit-shell-prompt-866/)  (but did not get) from `nohup`:  `setsid command` will [create a new process group](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setsid.2.html) for `<command>` and make it the session leader of a new session. The `PGID` of this new process group will be unknown to the caller (`bash` in this case) so  we don't  need to use `nohup` anymore.

So, use `setsid` instead of `nohup` and you're done (I only now see Mark Plotnick's comment, which is right on the money. Oh well, I hope my answer also clarifies the *reason* why `setsid` is the better alternative in this case)

Comment: Thank you Hans,  that provides the exact explanation as well as the solution I needed.  I have marked this as the preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

Okay... it seems the problem was actually being caused by the environment.

The shell was being run in a docker container.  and it seems Docker Exec is the one terminating all processes in the same Process Group, not the shell.  Or at least that appears to be the case.

However I still find it weird that a program backgrounded from ".bashrc" inherits the same process group as the parent shell, BUT exactly the same backgrounding command from the command line gets its own seperate process group.

Once I discovered this was the cause, I discovered process groups was mentioned in the BASH manpage, with regard to Backgrounding a process, though it makes no mention of the difference starting it in the ".bashrc" vs CLI.

Answer (score -1):

Every bash process has a PPID (Parent PID)

If you run the following from terminal:

```
nohup tail -f /dev/null > /tmp/rand.txt &
```

The PPID from `ps -ef` output shows the PPID is init (First process to start):

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
user     18424     1  0 16:17 tty1     00:00:00 tail -f /dev/null
```

If you run the same command from bashrc the PPID is the bash process:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
user     16405 16404  0 Jun20 tty2     00:00:08 bash
user     18424 18386  0 16:17 tty1     00:00:00 tail -f /dev/null
```

When running from terminal the process will continue until init is stopped.

When running from bashrc the process will continue until bash is stopped.

Comment: Okay that makes some sense... I suppose...
But it does not explain why there is a difference, or how to get the background process started in the bashrc, to no longer have bash as the parent.    PS: I did try to double-background the process but perhaps I did it wrong.    I will do some further experiments.

Comment: Try spawning another Bash instance and starting the process from within that. I have to question the wisdom of starting background processes from your `.bashrc`, though - what happens if you start multiple Bash instances for interactive use? How do you control the process? What service does it provide which could not be better provided by other means?

Comment: @tripleee note is right on the money I would consider using crontab `@reboot` instead

Comment: There is a check to see if the process is already running, and if so another is not run.  Starting the process has never been a problem, keeping the process running after the shell exits, is the problem.

Comment: Nope... after further investigation the PPID is not the issue.  The "disown" program of bash seems to set the process parent to 0.  But the process continues to belong to the shells  PGID, but only if started from bashrc.